# Database design for simple scenario

Tags: database

I've got a scenario where an user can specify multiple positions for multiple Organisations. For eg, User A can have position manager for Organisation A, and position Director for Organisation B. What is the best way to model the scenario? Here is my design:

```
Tables:
Organisation(PK= organisation ID)
Positions (PK=PositionId, FK=OrganisationId)
User (UserId)
```

Comment: Make one more table suppose `Allocation(PK=Allocation ID, UserId = FK, organisation ID = FK, PositionId = FK)`. This will do it for you buddy

Comment: Sure. Should also be able to search user by position or organisation

Comment: @ user2383728 please check the comment above. Is that will solve your issue? By using that Allocation table you can  able to search user by position or organisation. Feel free  to reply me.